# How to get class name by using id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class, html-lists

I have a HTML Element, or list item, which has both an `id` and a `class` assigned to it. I am writing automated tests, and I need to check the `class` for this element. In the test, when I call `window.document.getElementById('my-element-id')`, it does return the correct element, but there is no `class` property on it. Is there another way to check the `class`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The property you're looking for is `className`.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xxEtj/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li id="myId" class="myClass">Item one</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var li = document.getElementById('myId');
alert(li.className);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt answer. I have `<li id="slide-18415" class="zoom-out">`. Are you saying that if I call the code that you have above (changing the variable names), it will display an alert that says "zoom-out"? If so, I don't think it is working for me for some reason. I am actually running these commands in PHP, but they go through selenium (helps with test automation) which runs them in the browser and returns the stuff. But I think that is working properly, because when I run `window.document.getElementById('slide-18415')`, it returns [object HTMLLIElement]. any more ideas?

Comment: What about if the `li` has more than one class?

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById('my-element-id').className
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt answer. I have `<li id="slide-18415" class="zoom-out">`. Are you saying that if I call the code that you have above (changing the variable names), it will return "zoom-out"? If so, I don't think it is working for me for some reason. I am actually running these commands in PHP, but they go through selenium (helps with test automation) which runs them in the browser and returns the stuff. But I think that is working properly, because when I run `window.document.getElementById('slide-18415')`, it returns [object HTMLLIElement]. any more ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate property is .className

EG: window.document.getElementById('my-element-id').className //returns "class-1 classes"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `className`.

```
document.getElementById('myelement').className
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `document.getElementById('my-element-id').className`, somehow it will not always return the classes string. This happened when I get a SVG element by using `document.getElementById`.

So, my recommendation would be using the `.getAttribute()`:

```js
document.getElementById('my-element-id').getAttribute('class')
```